# Reading dataframe from multiple input paths and adding columns simultaneously

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to read multiple input paths and based on the dates in the paths adding two columns to the data frame. Actually the files were stored as orc partitioned by these dates using hive so they have a structure like 
`s3n://bucket_name/folder_name/partition1=value1/partition2=value2`
where partition2 = mg_load_date . So here I am trying to fetch multiple directories from multiple paths and based on the partitions I have to create two columns namely mg_load_date and event_date for each spark dataframe. I am reading these as input and combining them after I add these two columns finding the dates for each file respectively.

Is there any other way since I have many reads for each file, to read all the files at once while adding two columns for their specific rows. Or any other way where I can make the read operation fast since I have many reads.
I guess reading all the files like this `sqlContext.read.format('orc').load(inputpaths)` is faster than reading them individually and then merging them.

Any help is appreciated.

```
dfs = []
for i in input_paths:
    df = sqlContext.read.format('orc').load(i)  
    date = re.search('mg_load_date=([^/]*)/$', i).group(1)
    df = df.withColumn('event_date',F.lit(date)).withColumn('mg_load_date',F.lit(date))
    dfs+=[df]
df = reduce(DataFrame.unionAll,dfs)
```

Comment: There is no parallelism issue here. The only possible problem is execution plan. But why don't you just load from root and filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @user8371915 says, you should load your data from the root path instead of passing a list of subdirectory:

```
sqlContext.read.format('orc').load("s3n://bucket_name/folder_name/")
```

Then you'll have access to your partitioning columns `partition1` and `partition2`.

If for some reason you can't load from the root path you can try using `pyspark.sql.functions` `input_file_name` to get the name of the file for each row of your dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Spark 2.2.0+

to read from multiple folders using orc format.

```
df=spark.read.orc([path1,path2])
```

ref: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12334

Comment: Based on the file path, I also wanted to add a column specific to the file path in each input read. I don't think that would be possible.